# Traefik and custom certificate renewal

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a specific certificate generated by letsencrypt.

In my traefik config, I have:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-config
data:
  traefik.toml: |
    # traefik.toml
    defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]
    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
          [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
          certFile = "/etc/xxx/my-cert.crt"
          keyFile = "/etc/xxx/my-cert.key"

    [acme] # Automatically add Let's Encrypt Certificate.
      storage= "/etc/certificate/acme.json"
      email = "john.doe@company.com"
       entryPoint = "https"
       onHostRule = true
       caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
        [acme.dnsChallenge]
        provider = "route53"
        delayBeforeCheck = 0
    [[acme.domains]]
      main = "*.company.com"
    #[[acme.domains]]
    #  main = "*.espace-client.company.com"
```

Thing is my certicate :

```
/etc/xxx/my-cert.crt
```

will end in 10 days.

I also have the a certificate for the wild card: `*.company.com`

Will traefik renew it automatically or should I do something ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the certificate should never end in 10 days. Something must be wrong.

> "If there are less than 30 days remaining before the certificate
>   expires, Traefik will attempt to renew it automatically."

You should check the logs of your traefik container:

```
docker logs traefik-container
```